# Create bridged networking in KVM without libvirt

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I've created a bridge on the host with a method similar to the one here:

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_libvirt_just_auto_configure_a_regular_network_bridge.3F

However, to link the guest machine to the bridge, the doc suggests something like this in the libvirt config file:

```
 <interface type='bridge'>
    <source bridge='br0'/>
    <mac address='00:16:3e:1a:b3:4a'/>
 </interface>
```

However, I do not want to use libvirt. How can this be achieved by specifying options to the command line on the creation of the guest via the 'kvm' command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an image with virt-install, it tells libvirt to start kvm with:

```
kvm [more options] -net nic,macaddr=54:52:00:52:1c:7c,vlan=0,model=virtio -net tap,fd=7,script=,vlan=0,ifname=vnet0
```

I created [a post](http://blog.bigsmoke.us/2009/12/09/debian-network-bridge-setup-for-kvmqemu) about creating VM's with KVM and libvirt. I just use that blog to remember stuff, but perhaps it is of use to you.

Comment: +1: Just replaced 3 bookmarks I'd had for the same reason with one to your blog post.  Very helpful.

Comment: +1: Great! Thanks for sharing. I don't know how long I've looked for exactly this information...